# replace string with square brackets

Tags: javascript, replace

I wanted to replace the string including '?' and '[text]'. I tried with all the options, but not working. Those are special characters. How can we handle these ones.

```
src = src.replace('text=?', 'textNew=?');
src = src.replace('[text]', 'textNew');
```

Comment: please add some examples of source and target strings.

Comment: hi, could you give us real case input and expected output ?

Comment: ^^ replace works with a string as first parameter as well.

Comment: Wait, you're right. I was mistaken, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using RegExp object (Regular Expression implementation)

```
var a = "text=?othertext"
var b ="[text]othertext"
var r1= new RegExp("text=\\\?","g");
var r2= new RegExp("\\\[text\\\]","g");

var a_replaced = a.replace(r1,"textNew=?")
var b_replaced = b.replace(r2,"textNew")
```

`?` and `[` and `]` are special characters in RegExp. You have to escape them with triple `\`.

the `g` option in RegExp call, replace ALL the occurences of the substring in the string

https://regex101.com/ a service to test regular expression (adapted for various language)

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp the W3C documentation

Comment: it does not help, if the problem is not clear. even with the given strings for searching from op it works.

Comment: I add link to documentation and online tester. Hoping this helps you

Comment: It is working fine. you saved me a lot.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex for Replacing special Characters

```
src = src.replace(/\[text\]/,'textNew');
src = src.replace(/text=\?/,"textNew=?");
```

here \ is used to allow Special Characters in string